# Spring-Boot: Debugging in Intellij - how to see name of reloaded classes

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using Intellij IDEA with a Spring Boot project.

During debugging, I see a message in the debug sub window:
`myConfigurationName: 2 classes reloaded`

[Message: myConfigurationName: 2 classes reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MTOY.jpg).

Where can I see the name of these classes?

***UPDATE:***

Even if I update the file `build-log.properties` with the following, I cannot see the class names in `build.log`.

```
log4j.rootLogger=trace, info, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=$LOG_FILE_PATH$
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20Mb
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%7r] %6p - %30.30c - %m\n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1} - %m%n`
```

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available in IntelliJ IDEA, related request:

- [IDEABKL-5543](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5543) HotSwap does not show the list of reloaded classes

You can find the names of the changed classes in [build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Debug output will contain something like this (`Main.java` was changed):

```
2017-04-06 22:12:13,074 [  20509]  DEBUG - ps.incremental.fs.BuildFSState - Module 'stopme' production: MARKED DIRTY: D:\work\attaches\stopme\src\com\jetbrains\support\Main.java
2017-04-06 22:12:13,080 [  20515]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - Cleaning output files:
2017-04-06 22:12:13,080 [  20515]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - D:/work/attaches/stopme/out/production/stopme/com/jetbrains/support/Main.class
2017-04-06 22:12:13,080 [  20515]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - End of files
2017-04-06 22:12:13,105 [  20540]  DEBUG - kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder - Build result: NOTHING_DONE
2017-04-06 22:12:13,106 [  20541]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - Compiling files:
2017-04-06 22:12:13,106 [  20541]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - D:/work/attaches/stopme/src/com/jetbrains/support/Main.java
2017-04-06 22:12:13,106 [  20541]  DEBUG - gging.ProjectBuilderLoggerImpl - End of files
2017-04-06 22:12:13,108 [  20543]   INFO - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling 1 java files; module: stopme
2017-04-06 22:12:13,108 [  20543]  DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling D:\work\attaches\stopme\src\com\jetbrains\support\Main.java
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the logging properties for that (see my edited question), but still I cannot see the class names.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed it to `log4j.rootLogger=trace, file` and still no class names in the log. But I can see in the target.*.* folders the *.class files. And looking at the creation date I can see the changed class names. So this is ok as a workaround.

Comment: I've added the example of DEBUG log showing which files were changed and recompiled (and therefore reloaded).